# How do I keep strings in first column with tidyr::gather?

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

This may be a very basic question about `tidyr`, which I just started learning, but I don't seem to find an answer after much searching in SO and Google.

Suppose I have a data frame:

```
mydf<- data.frame(name=c("Joe","Mary","Bob"),
                  jan=1:3,
                  feb=4:6,
                  mar=7:9,
                  apr=10:12)
```

which I want to reshape from wide to long. Before, I used `melt`, so:

```
library(reshape)
melt(mydf,id.vars = "name",measure.vars = colnames(mydf)[-1])
```

Which produces

```
   name variable value
1   Joe      jan     1
2  Mary      jan     2
3   Bob      jan     3
4   Joe      feb     4
5  Mary      feb     5
6   Bob      feb     6
7   Joe      mar     7
8  Mary      mar     8
9   Bob      mar     9
10  Joe      apr    10
11 Mary      apr    11
12  Bob      apr    12
```

I wanted to use `tidyr::gather`, so I tried

```
gather(mydf,month,sales,jan:apr)
```

Which produces

```
   name month sales
1     2   jan     1
2     3   jan     2
3     1   jan     3
4     2   feb     4
5     3   feb     5
6     1   feb     6
7     2   mar     7
8     3   mar     8
9     1   mar     9
10    2   apr    10
11    3   apr    11
12    1   apr    12
```

I'm lost here, as I haven't been able to keep the names in the first column.

What am I missing here?

**######### EDIT TO ADD #######**

```
> R.Version()$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)"
> packageVersion("tidyr")
[1] ‘0.3.0’
```

Comment: It works fine for me on tidyr version 0.2.0 and R 3.2.2

Comment: @RichardScriven, I have `tidyr` 0.3.0 and R 3.2.2. Could be something in the new version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in tidyr 0.3.0 you will need to convert the factor column `name` to character.  I'm not sure why that has changed from version 0.2.0, where it worked without conversion to character. Nevertheless, here we go ...

```
gather(transform(mydf, name = as.character(name)), month, sales, jan:apr)
#    name month sales
# 1   Joe   jan     1
# 2  Mary   jan     2
# 3   Bob   jan     3
# 4   Joe   feb     4
# 5  Mary   feb     5
# 6   Bob   feb     6
# 7   Joe   mar     7
# 8  Mary   mar     8
# 9   Bob   mar     9
# 10  Joe   apr    10
# 11 Mary   apr    11
# 12  Bob   apr    12

R.version.string
# [1] "R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)"
packageVersion("tidyr")
# [1] ‘0.3.0’
```

Credit to @aosmith for finding the closed github issue.  You should be able to use the development version without issue now.  To install the dev version, use

```
devtools::install_github(
    "hadley/tidyr", 
    ref = "2e08772d154babcc97912bcae8b0b64b65b964ab"
)
```

Comment: I don't know.  I'm reading the docs and haven't found anything yet nor have I seen any [issues reported](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues)

Comment: This looks like this [issue](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues/104) that was closed today.